# Erro NoClassDefFoundError após remover API externa (YouTube)

Tags: java, android, android-gradle

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto bacana e me deparei com uma dificuldade que não consegui sair ontem, o projeto parou de reconhecer todas as api's, butterknife, YouTube, tudo...

Segue o erro:

> NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no
>   stack available

```
Didn't find class "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/br.com.dev_sirox.bandmember-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: Acredito que tenha relação com o Android Manifest, pois tinha incluído uma classe ali, verei mais quando chegar a noite em casa

Comment: Acredito que tenha relação com o Android Manifest, pois tinha incluído uma classe ali, verei mais quando chegar a noite em casa

Comment: Adicione o erro na pergunta, não deixe que o erro dependa de consulta externa ao site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu erro não mostra em qual linha ele quebra?
Uma das respostas abaixo pode ajudar você a resolver seu problema.

1- Tente "Clean" e "Sync Project with Gradle Files". Rode seu projeto

2- Pode ser que seu pacote no manifest.xml e da sua MainActivity estejam diferentes.

3- Desabilitar o "Instant Run"

Comment: Ele quebra quando chama classe do Firebase e Youtube, ou seja, qualquer API

Comment: Adicionei o erro no topo

Comment: poderia postar o manifest também?

Comment: pelo que eu pesquisei, esse tipo de erro acontece por conta de arquivos temporários, ou alguma declaração de package errada no manifest.

Comment: tente desinstalar o app e instalar novamente.

Comment: velho, do nada ocorreu erro bug no meu Android Studio, na empresa onde trabalho estava com o mesmo bug e tinha atualizado, resolveu, porra velho, coisa sinistra essa que fode do nada! Fiz esse último procedimento Desabilitar o "Instant Run" e resolveu!!! Mas eu gosto desse recurso!!!

Comment: Concordo com você, é um recurso muito bom! porém ele da uns problemas.

Comment: Vira e mexe ele não reconhece alterações feitas no projeto, e pelo visto causa esse erro também.

Comment: Amigo, caso a resposta lhe ajudou marque como a resposta correta pois pode ajudar outras pessoas, grato!

Comment: eu desativei o instant run e resolveu...obrigado pela ajuda ^^